# IntelliJ can not find dependencies added to compileClasspath

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I'm writing some Spark code and compiling into an uber-jar. As is typical for that application you don't want the Spark libraries to be in the jar as they will be provided on the cluster and they're big. The typical trick is that your `build.gradle` looks something like:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'some.library:lib:0.1'

    provided 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0'
}
```

This works from the command line fine. Everything compiles and I can deploy to the Spark cluster without issues. However, IntelliJ gets confused and reports "unresolved reference: spark" for things like `import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD`.

How do I keep the dependency out of my jar and keep IntelliJ happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution: [the `idea` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html):

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

idea.module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [ configurations.provided ]
}

dependencies {
    compile 'some.library:lib:0.1'

    provided 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0'
}
```

it's annoying to have to add an extra plugin and more code the build for this kind of thing but it seems to work.